# Java: for-loop can only execute once

Tags: java, loops, csv, static

I have two class fiels, one is named CSVUtils.java and the other one is named FilesCollector.java. The CSVUtils.java contains a static method named matchValues(String csvFile, int columnNumber, String matchValue) that is called by the FilesCollector.java. Basically it is like this

```
Public Class CSVUtils {

    private static String FILENAME;
    private static int COLUMN;
    private static String MATCHVALUE;
  public static void matchValues(String csvFile, int columnNumber, String matchValue) {
    try {  
     //read csvFile, match values, and write to outPut file. details omitted.
   } finally {
        csvReader.close();
        csvWriter.close();
        System.out.println("success");
        System.exit(0); 
    }

  }
}
```

In FilesCollector.java, I use the Apache Commons-IO to fetch a list of CSV files and store it in an array File[] csvFiles. I then use the below for-loop to process individual csv file

```
for (File e : csvFiles) {
  CSVUtils.matchValues(e.getAbsolutePath(), 9, "Yes");
}
```

However, for some reason I don't know, this above for-loop can only process the first csv file in File[] csvFiles array. Can you guys help me where might be wrong in my code? Thanks a lot!

edit: after commenting out this line System.exit(0);  my code is working. Why this line of code made the method not work?

Comment: Is really `csvFiles.length > 1` ?

Comment: yes, in FilesCollector.java, I tested the size of csvFiles array.

Comment: System.exit(0) closes the program. It can't continue the for loop if the program closes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your finally block you call `System.exit(0)`, so after you process one file you shutdown your program.

Hence whatever the `length` of `csvFiles` is, you'll process only the first file.

```
finally {
        csvReader.close();
        csvWriter.close();
        System.out.println("success");
        System.exit(0); <--- here
    }
```

Remove this line and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are shutting down the program with

```
System.exit(0);
```

so it doesn't continue.